# Retrieving a partition UUID from a disk image (GPT)

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning

I have been working on a custom Linux distro, and I have created a bootable UEFI disk image.
The disk image has two partitions:

- the EFI partition
- a BTRFS partition that will be the root filesystem.

In an attempt to make the boot process as simple as possible, I have decided to not use an `initramfs` and instead have opted to pass the partition UUID from the BTRFS partition to the kernel via the `root=PARTUUID=<uuid>` option.

While I have been able to create the partition table (GPT) and create the two partitions, I have not been able to get the BTRFS partition UUID to pass to the kernel so that it will be mounted as the root filesystem.

What would be the best way to retrieve the UUID of a partition from a GPT disk image?

So far, I have tried creating a loopback device from the entire disk image.  However, after doing this, I was unable to view the device in blkid.

Comment: What did you do in terms of research on how to get the UUID? (besides [asking the same question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63419515/get-gpt-partition-uuid-from-disk-image))

Comment: Please, pretty please, indicate what you've tried so far, which searches you've done, and why the results are not satisfactory.

Comment: I have tried making the entire disk image a loopback device, but when I run blkid, the loopback device doesn't show up.

Comment: That's fine, feel free to edit your question and integrate that as one of the things you've tried. Did you try doing a websearch [for your question](https://www.google.com/search?q=retrieve+the+UUID+of+a+partition+from+a+GPT+disk+image)? Besides your own questions, a similar question on serverfault comes up. Did you try the things suggested there? If so, what did you try and why did it not work?